# Check Firebase Child value in kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set up a database app, but I'm stuck for a bit.

I want everyone to be able to write data into the database, the this is.. If a piece of info already exists the data should not be overwritten.

Example:

- Person A adds:  cd-title + BandA
- The database will save this info under two children

  ```
  personA private --->
               Cd-title, Band A

  Database --->
        Cd-title, Band A
  ```
- Person B adds: cd-title + BandA

  ```
  personB private --->
               Cd-title, Band A

  Database--->
       // error child already exists
  ```

Code-wise should be like

```
get value. child
       if !=null
         error child already exists
       if = null
         info succesfully saved

   val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Wishlist/$uid/$album")

        val Vinyl_piece = Albumadd(aAlbum, bBand, nName, gGenre, bBuildyear, SideA1, SideA2, SideA3, SideA4, SideA5)

        ref.setValue(Vinyl_piece)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a value to the database, based on the existing value (or lack thereof) at that same location, you'll need to [use a Firebase Database transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

In your case that'd look something like:

```
postRef.runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {
    override fun doTransaction(mutableData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
        if (mutableData.value == null) {
            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.value = Vinyl_piece
        }
        return Transaction.success(mutableData)
    }

    override fun onComplete(
        databaseError: DatabaseError?,
        b: Boolean,
        dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?
    ) {
        // Transaction completed
        Log.d(TAG, "runTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError!!)
    }
})
```

Comment: I think you're missing an `else`